# Why am I getting authorization code is not in a recognised format?

Tags: oauth, postman

Hello everyone I need help please. This is about Seatgeek Oauth request.
In Postman, entered the required fields to get access token.However I am getting this error below.

{
"status": 400,
"message": "Oauth code invalid",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Oauth code invalid",
"short_message": "Code invalid",
"verbose_message": "The authorization code provided was not in a recognized format.",
"hint_message": "Switch code verifier",
"category": null,
"parameter": null,
"code": 40322
}
],
"meta": {
"status": 400
}
}

Now let me add the endpoints I used
Base endpoint: https://api.seatgeek.com/2/oauth/access_token

Params: client_id = xxxxxxxxx
Params: scope = offline_access,read-user-first-name,read-user-email,read-user-phone,view-soundersfc-crm-id
Params:grant_type = authorization_code

Body:x-www-form-urlencoded:
client_secret = xxxxxxxxxxx
code = “ ”

The full url will be something like this : https://api.seatgeek.com/2/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&scope=offline_access,read-user-first-name,read-user-email,read-user-phone,view-soundersfc-crm-id&grant_type=authorization_code

Please help me identify this code error. Any help will be highly appreciated

here is the Seatgeek Oauth documentation.
https://partners.seatgeek.com/enterprise-client-integration/oauth

Comment: Looks like you mangled two different steps together into one here? The `scope` parameter needs to be passed when you _request_ the user's authorization. You are trying to pass it in the _next_ step, when you are supposed to exchange the `code` (which you failed to pass at all) for an access token.

Comment: @CBroe how do I do that please.With or without the Scope I get the same error. Should I pass it as a header or what.I'm new to this Oauth authentication.

Comment: You need to create the authorization URL from step 5 first, and then redirect the user there. After confirmation, the user will be redirected back to your specified `redirect_url`, and that one will have the `code` appended as a GET parameter.

Comment: ok @Cbroe I get you now.I have the redirect Uri already.However should I pass the redirect Uri as  a params or header or body?

Comment: Neither. You need to _redirect_ the user to it, in their own browser.

Comment: ok I see. Can you walk me through or post a link to a youtube video. Thanks alot by the @Cbroe

Comment: I did try the redirect URI before as params,headers and body to no avail.Some Oauth I think allows that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250163/discussion-between-joe-voidable-and-cbroe).

Comment: Some implementations require that you pass the redirect_uri value to the code exchange endpoint as an additional security measure. But that doesn't change the fact that you need to send the user to that URL first, otherwise you don't get the necessary `code` to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe it worked. Problem was on their end.Some of the scopes were invalid.Had to delete all and allow offline access only.Thanks for the help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SeatGeek API OAuth](https://partners.seatgeek.com/enterprise-client-integration/oauth#step-3-prepare-your-application-to-receive-the-authorization-code) documentation not accuracy. you need a little change a scope.

(just use `offline_access`)

### #1 Using this URL from Browser

```
https://seatgeek.com/oauth2?scope=offline_access&client_id=MzA...zcy
```

### #2 You can get the code in URL address of browser

It will return your registered `redirect URL` and `code`
[image]

Copy that `code` and call POST to get token by curl

### #3 Get token

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/oauth/access_token" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' \
     --data-urlencode "code={received_code_from_#2}" \
     --data-urlencode "client_id={your_client_id}" \
     --data-urlencode "client_secret={your_client_secret}" \
     --data-urlencode "grant_type=authorization_code"
```

[image]

Note #1
you can get the client id /secret from [developer portal](https://seatgeek.com/account/develop)
[image]

Note #2
code is JWT format. The payload is this content.
I decoded from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

[image]

Comment: yes it is working now

Comment: I am happy to address your problem